# aws lambda Cannot find package aws-jwt-verify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have been implementing an AWS lambda function (node.js v18) which already worked with the following dependencies in package.json

```
"@aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi": "^3.428.0",
"@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider": "^3.490.0",
"@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.405.0",
"@aws-sdk/client-ses": "^3.485.0",
"@aws-sdk/client-ssm": "^3.496.0",
"@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb": "^3.427.0"
```

Today, I add the new dependency `"aws-jwt-verify": "^4.0.0"`.
Local test was successful with the new dependency used. However, when the lamda code was executed in AWS, it reported the following error in CloudWatch:

```
2024-01-30T21:42:29.670Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot find package 'aws-jwt-verify' imported from /var/task/cognito.js",
    "code": "ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND",
    "stack": [
        "Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'aws-jwt-verify' imported from /var/task/cognito.js",
        "    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)",
        "    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:895:9)",
        "    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:988:20)",
        "    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:939:12)",
        "    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1181:79)",
        "    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)",
        "    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:835:30)",
        "    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)",
        "    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)",
        "    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36)"
    ]
}
```

I really couldn't see why "aws-jwt-verify" is treated differently than other packages.
In my code file cognito.js:

```
import { CognitoIdentityProviderClient, DescribeUserPoolClientCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider';
import { CognitoJwtVerifier } from 'aws-jwt-verify';
```

where the last line was newly added and caused the issue in aws (worked perfectly in local test).

Could someone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that "aws-jwt-verify" must be added to the nodejs runtime because it does not already exist there (like other @aws-sdk packages).

Comment: hey , how can i do the same as im also struggling with it as a beginner

Comment: Hey, I read the info here https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-import-module-error-nodejs to understand that 3rd dependencies must be made available. The link mentioned the best practice is to create a Lambda layer. For my quick test, I just uploaded node_modules/aws-jwt-verify together with my lambda handler and it also worked but I can no longer view/edit code in Lambda web console because the deployment package became too large for inline code editing.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: if you wish to test your lambda locally with docker, here you go:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20

# Copy function code
COPY index.js ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
  
# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "index.handler" ]
```

You could install your dependencies locally and set up your layer.

You then put all your code in `index.js`

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).